# Exact mechanics of time limits during Google App Engine Python's urlfetch?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a http request in my code that takes ~5-10 s to run.  Through searching this site, I've found the code to increase the limit before timeout:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline(60)
```

My question: What is that number '60'?  Seconds or tenths of a second?  Most responses seem to imply it's seconds, but that can't be right.  When I use 60, I get a time out in less than 10 s while testing on localhost.  I have to set the number to at least 100 to avoid the issue - which I worry will invoke the ire of the Google gods.

Answer (score 0):

It's seconds, you can passed it in the fetch function. Have you tried to fetch another website? Are you sure it's a timeout not another error?
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/fetchfunction